# DOMPDF no me muestra los resultado de la tabla cuando mando a generar el pdf

Tags: php, dompdf

Estoy consumiendo una API pequeña, la cual al digitar el id consulta y mando los resultados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al intentar generar el pdf, el documento solo me muestra el h1, label, input y el botón, pero no me muestra los resultados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
adjunto código, para que por favor me puedan ayudar

```
<?php
    include_once "./vendor/autoload.php";

    use Dompdf\Dompdf;

    if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != "") {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $url = "http://localhost/rest/api/" . $id;

        $client = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($client);

        $result = json_decode($response);

        if ($result->id == NULL) {
            echo "<br /><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
            ID no existe!
            </div>";
        } else {
            echo "<br /><table class='table'>";
            echo "<tr><th>ID:</th><td>$result->id</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><th>Nombre:</th><td>$result->Nombre</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><th>Celular:</th><td>$result->celular</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><th>Correo:</th><td>$result->correo</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><th>Monto:</th><td>$$result->amount</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";

            echo "<form method='POST'>
            <button type='submit' name='submit_pdf' class='btn btn-success'>Generar PDF</button>
            </form>";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST["submit_pdf"])) {
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $html = ob_get_clean();
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=documento.pdf");
        echo $dompdf->output();?>
```

Comment: Puedes verificar si al procesar el POST del botón de generar PDF, `$_POST['id']` tiene un valor o no. Es muy posible que, al generar este nuevo evento POST, tu formulario no tiene ese valor (sólo tiene el botón) y no "se supone" que deba conservar nada. Explora la posibilidad de usar $_SESSION, de añadir el id en el form del botón (que corre riesgo de ser manipulado por el usuario antes de su envío), etc.

Comment: Me podrias explicar por favor como lo haria, estoy investigando y no me queda claro como lo puedo implementar @Alfabravo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que generas el HTML solo cuando consultas el ID, pero no cuando quieres crear el PDF.

```
// Aquí va a entrar para consulta y para generar el PDF
if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != "") {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $url = "http://localhost/rest/api/" . $id;

    $client = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($client);

    $result = json_decode($response);

    if ($result->id == NULL) {
        echo "<br /><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
        ID no existe!
        </div>";
    } else {
        echo "<br /><table class='table'>";
        // Encierra entre llaves las variables
        echo "<tr><th>ID:</th><td>{$result->id}</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><th>Nombre:</th><td>{$result->Nombre}</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><th>Celular:</th><td>{$result->celular</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><th>Correo:</th><td>{$result->correo</td></tr>";
        // Escapa el $ agregando \ al inicio
        echo "<tr><th>Monto:</th><td>\${$result->amount}</td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";

        // Evitar incluir botón en PDF
        if(!isset($_POST['submit_pdf'])) {
            // Incluye ID para volver a generar formato
            echo "<form method='POST'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$result->id}'>
            <button type='submit' name='submit_pdf' class='btn btn-success'>Generar PDF</button>
            </form>";
        }
    }
}
// El HTML ya se generó previamente
if (isset($_POST['submit_pdf'])) {
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=documento.pdf");
    echo $dompdf->output();
}
```

Quiero suponer que en alguna parte de tu código tienes `ob_start()`, de lo contrario, no serviría el `ob_get_clean()` ni podrías enviar encabezados.

Comment: Eres un crack, muchas gracias de verdad, me funciono